# Reference for proof that an SDE with locally Lipschitz coefficients and linear growth has a unique strong solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

Let W be a q dimensional Brownian motion on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in [0,T]},\mathbb{P})$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $b:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d},\sigma:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d \times q}$ be measureable s.t. $b$ and $\sigma$ are locally Lipschitz and with linear growth.

I can not find any reference for a proof that in this case we have a unique strong solution to the SDE

$$ dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dW_t, X_0=x_0.$$

I would be very grateful for a reference.

Comment: Oksendal or Mao's books on SDEs. Also Evan's book on SDE and Steel's book on stochastic calculus for finance.

Comment: I can not find this in Oksendal's book. Where exactly do you find this result in his book?

Comment: You may look at the index at the beginning of the book.

Comment: Yes, that idea occurred to me. But I can only find a theorem assuming a global Lipschitz assumption. Are you sure that the book contains the result?

Comment: Isn't the global Lipschitz condition what you wrote in your question? By the way, the constant $C$ should be different. Or is that what you area asking? You want the same constant in both conditions?

Comment: Oh sorry! I was searching for a result where we replace globally Lipschitz by locally Lipschitz. I only wrote it correctly in the headline. I will correct this.

Comment: In Mao's book you have the proof with the local Lipschitz condition. It's not fully detailed but using also the the fully detailed proof with the global condition, you should be able to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! Just one more question: Do they proof the existence of a strong solution? So is the solution a function of the brownian motion?

Comment: Yes, they prove it.